# passing a list pointer to a function rather than the list

Tags: python, list, recursion

Is it possible to pass a (moving) pointer to a list start into a function in Python?

I have a recursive function working on a section of a list. The list itself is not changed, only the pointer to a 'starting-point' into it. The problem I ran into was that long lists killed the code with memory overrun.

Here is the code:

```
def trim(l):
    print("list len= ", len(l))
    if len(l)!= 1:
        trim(l[1:])
    else:
        print("done")
```

The above example is contrived, my actual code does different stuff than just trimming the list, but it also has a moving start-pointer. A list of 1 million integers blew out of memory on a 10G RAM machine.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Python doesn't have pointers. You can try passing around indices instead of a slice, which creates copies. You can also consider using `numpy` which provides object-oriented primitive arrays where slicing creates views, not copies. There is also the built-in `array` module, which provides space efficient primitive arrays of sized numerical types. Both of these array approaches should provide orders of magnitude space saving. A million 64bit ints is about 8 megabytes

Comment: You may find the [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque) data structure useful. Instead of passing a slice (which is a shallow copy of all elements), you can use `l.popleft()` to remove an element from the head of the deque. This doesn't incur the copying cost of `l.pop(0)` when `l` is a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just pass the index instead of passing the whole new list?

So you would call `trim(l, 0)` and then check the index against the length of the list, and then call `trim(l, 1)` if needed.

```
def trim(l, idx):
    print("list len = ", (len(l) - idx))
    if idx < (len(x) - 1):
        trim(l, idx + 1)
    else:
        print("done")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing a non-tail-call recursive function to iterate over a list, your problem is more likely to be a stack overflow, or out-of-memory error related to the stack size.

I recommend re-writing this with an integer pointer and a for-loop, as it seems that Python doesn't have tail-call optimisation.

Here's a guess at what you might be wanting to do:

```
x = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4]

def trim_leading_zero(l):
  the_len = len(l)
  start_i = 0
  for i in xrange(the_len):
    if l[i] != 0:
      return l[i:]

>>> trim_leading_zero(x)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

It's not clear from your code what it's meant to actually do. If you're trying to actually return a sequence, then you may want to look at Generators, which don't require holding an entire sequence in memory.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with large data, use **generators** instead of regular iterators.

```
def trim(l):
    print("list len= ", len(l))
    pointer = 0
    if len(l)!= 1:
        yield l[pointer:]
        pointer += 1
    else:
        print("done")

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for i in trim(x):
    print i

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Generators will yield **one item at a time** and let you do whatever you need with it, *avoiding create the whole list first before processing.* If you want to get a list out of it, you can simply do `list(trim(x))`.

There are great explanations of `yield` and `generators` here - [What does the yield keyword do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)